# writing select clause with times

Tags: sql, select, time

I would like to write a sql clause like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE orderdate < {orderdate three years after};
```

I tried some `dateadd` function, but I didn't find an example to fit just my needs. Any help?

Comment: You could just do `select * from table`, because `ORDERDATE` will always be smaller than `ORDERDATE + 3 years`?

Comment: @mjgirl - I think you need to add more detail to your question before you will get a useful answer.

Comment: Did you mean (a) to select orders that are 3+ years old? Or should that be (b) orders that are 3+ years older than the latest order in the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server:

`... WHERE orderdate < DATEADD(year, 3, orderdate)`

Documentation and examples here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Maybe I've not understood your question correctly but that seems to be a pointless query, as Konerak commented.

Comment: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from db_orders where order_date < DATEADD(year,3, order_date]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: @mjgirl - You have no closing bracket for the `DATEADD` function.

Comment: No pointless...aim is to get rows of exprired orders, and order exprises certain years after orderdate.

Comment: @mjgirl - If that is the case you don't want to compare the order date to *itself* but to the current date: `SELECT * FROM db_orders WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > DATEADD(year, 3, order_date)`

Comment: @mjgirl - Have you tested the query against the database using Management Studio? If the query works and returns the expected rows then your problem is now in your Java code, for which you'd have to post a new question ;)

Comment: @mjgirl - Can you first confirm you are using SQL Server (just so we are using the same SQL dialect) and can you add to your question the SQL giving the error. You should also try replacing the `Now()` function with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and run the query again.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL

```
select * from table 
where orderdate < DATEADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 YEARS)
```

Comment: Doesn't this add years to current date?

Comment: Yes. You should explain what you want better: your question is asking for orderdate<orderdate+3, which will always be true... any number is smaller than the number +3 ... see my first comment on your question.